# How to get DISTINCT values from the database?

Tags: java, android, sql, select, distinct

I would like to get values from the database in this format

1   Audi
3   Nissan

But I am getting like this as of now. I don't need to get to include the _id in the output.But I couldn't eliminate as it throws a NullPointerException when I remove it.

```
id  MAKE
========= 
1   Audi  
2   Audi  
3   Nissan  
4   Audi
```

this is my query I have used in

```
cursor = db.rawQuery(
    "SELECT DISTINCT _id,MAKE FROM "+SQLiteAdapter.MYDATABASE_TABLE+
    " WHERE MAKE || ' ' || MODEL LIKE ?", new String[]{"%" + "" + "%"}
);
```

Do have I to change the sequence entirely to get the output or make changes on the above code.Thanks.

my code

```
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT SERIES FROM "+SQLiteAdapter.MYDATABASE_TABLE+" WHERE YEAR=2012 AND MAKE='Audi' AND MODEL=?", new String[]{"A6"});

adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.employee_list_item, cursor, new String[] {"series"}, new int[] {R.id.firstName});

employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: what is the purpose of your `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I have the where clause for constraint from previous values.Could you tell me how to do without the where clause & _id.

Comment: Hi Karthik, for the above mentioned output you dont need to DISTINCT to both column, just distinct to "MAKE" column only & you will get the output you want.

Comment: @Lucifer I am trying to do a drill down in my code,so only I decided to use DISTINCT in it.

Comment: @Lucifer you can't add distinct only on one column. You add distinct, it works on both columns

Comment: @Sathya I have tried DISTINCT seprately it works like a charm,I have an auto incremental _id in my database,when I try to implement it in the adapter it throws an NullPointerException of asking _id in it.I have added my rest of the code above.

Comment: What's wrong with `SELECT MIN(_id), MAKE ... GROUP BY MAKE`?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
select min(id), min(make) from cars group by make
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use SQLiteQueryBuilder's buildQueryString method:

```
buildQueryString (boolean distinct, String tables, String[] columns, String where, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy, String limit)
```